# Snowflake - How to split value and set a flag based on condtion

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have below table in which column code have values split with ';'
table customer

```
id | code
1  | 101;102
2  | 103;104
3  | 102;103;104
4  | 105
```

Now i want to create a new table cust_status  from customer where in new column status need to added
with an condition

```
if code value is in 101,102,103,104 then status 1
else status 0
---------------------
id | code       | status
1  | 101;102    | 1
2  | 103;104    | 1
3  | 102;103;104| 1
4  | 105        | 0
```

how to set the status value in snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a CTE. For this example I created a table called `so_question` and populated it with the data provided in the OP.

The code uses hardcoding of the codes corresponding to `status = 1`, if this is

```
WITH codes_preprocessing AS (
SELECT
    ID
    , CODE
    , SPLIT(CODE,';') AS CODES
    , CASE WHEN ARRAY_SIZE(ARRAY_INTERSECTION(CODES,['101','102','103','104'])) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS STATUS
FROM so_question
)
SELECT
    ID
    , CODE
    , status
FROM codes_preprocessing;
```

Comment: I think `ARRAY_OVERLAPS()` would be even better since it stops checking after the first match, and already returns a boolean

Answer (score 0):

One option is to search each code for valid values and return 1 if there's match.

This is Oracle syntax (for demonstration purposes):

```
SQL> select id, code,
  2    case when instr(code, '101') > 0 or
  3              instr(code, '102') > 0 or
  4              instr(code, '103') > 0 or
  5              instr(code, '104') > 0
  6         then 1
  7         else 0
  8    end status
  9  from test;

        ID CODE            STATUS
---------- ----------- ----------
         1 101;102              1
         2 103;104              1
         3 102;103;104          1
         4 105                  0

SQL>
```

In **Snowflake**, you'd use [`position`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/position) function instead, i.e.

```
select id, code,
  case when position(code, '101') > 0 or
            position(code, '102') > 0 or
            position(code, '103') > 0 or
            position(code, '104') > 0 
       then 1
       else 0
  end status
from test;
```

---

Alternatively, you could create additional table (let's call it `status`) which contains list of values that represent status 1 and then join it to existing table:

```
SQL> select * From status;

      CODE
----------
       101
       102
       103
       104

SQL> select distinct a.id, a.code,
  2    case when instr(a.code, b.code) > 0 then 1
  3         else 0
  4    end status
  5  from test a left join status b on instr(a.code, b.code) > 0;

        ID CODE            STATUS
---------- ----------- ----------
         1 101;102              1
         2 103;104              1
         3 102;103;104          1
         4 105                  0

SQL>
```

Or, in **Snowflake**,

```
select distinct a.id, a.code,
  case when position(a.code, b.code) > 0 then 1
       else 0 
  end status
from test a left join status b on position(a.code, b.code) > 0;
```